# Function call in for-loop bug

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

So I am currently writing my first program ever and a function in the for-loop creates a bug that causes the for-loop to not properly execute. All variables are properly declared in the code before, I am very new to this platform and programing in general so sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

```
function autoDraw(){
    var autoWinCount = 0;
    var autoGameCount = 0;
    var i = 0;
    autoNum = document.getElementById("autoNumID").value;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        autoGnum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*maxDraw);
        if(autoNum == autoGnum){
            autoWinCount++;
        } else{
        };
         autoGameCount++;
         addToLastResults(autoGnum); //without this function everything works as intended
         alert("Out of "+autoGameCount+" draws, you have won "+autoWinCount+". Which is a win percentage of "+autoWinPercentage+"%.");
    };
```

The for-loop does not properly execute, it stopps after 1 draw if the addToLastResults function is called.

```
function addToLastResults(newDraw){
    lastResults.reverse();                                                  
    lastResults.push(newDraw);
    lastResults.reverse();                                                 
    if(lastResults.length > maxLastResults){ 
        lastResults.pop();                                                 
    } else{
    };
    lastResults.toString();                                                 
    document.getElementById("lastResultsId").innerHTML = lastResults;
    lastResults = lastResults.split(",");                                   
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: could you describe the purpose of the code? What are you trying to accomplish? It seems a little confusing after reading it

Comment: It's a simple "lottery" where you can make the site draw a random number a set amount of times and display all the results. It works as intended without that 1 function call... @MattPengelly

Comment: "TypeError: lastResults.split is not a function" I get that even without that function call in the for-loop though. @zero298

Comment: The full code can be found here: https://github.com/l4wl1/learnProgramming/tree/master/Easy%20Lottery. I think the error is somewhere in either the loop or the function though since, as I said, without that function call in the for-loop it works. @MattPengelly

Comment: You need to assign the return value of lastResults.toString() back to lastResults. i.e. lastResults=lastResults.toString();

Comment: @user3357118 thanks so much man. do you know why it did work without the function call though?

Comment: If the function wasn't called, then it wouldn't throw the error to stop execution. I looked at your full script and don't see anywhere else you add content to lastResults, so I'm not sure how it would run as expected without calling the function, because the lastResults content in the HTML should have remained empty.

Comment: @user3357118    I called the function within the draw() function and it displayed the last results in the html properly.

Comment: The error was being thrown on the last line of the addToLastResults method, so it would have updated the HTML one time. if that did what you expected then that's probably the explanation.

Comment: @user3357118 ahh yeah, the draw function only added 1 lastResult. thanks so much for the help, really glad that people are so helpful here :)